# How do I hyphenate things like 'then-British Prime Minister'?

Tags: hyphens

What if a prefix is added not to just one word but to a multi-word phrase? What should I do in terms of hyphen(s) and blank(s)? 'Then-British Prime Minister'? 'Then British Prime Minister'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two dictionaries show "then" as an attributive adjective used without a hyphen. So, "then" in that sense is a word, rather than a prefix.

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=then) adj.
Being so at that time: *the then chairman of the board.*

[Merriam-Webster "then" adj](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/then)
: existing or acting at or belonging to the time mentioned *the then secretary of state*

Comment: The 'then British Prime Minister' would be ambiguous and could mean a Prime Minister who was British at the time being discussed, but later was not.

Comment: The majority would not interpret it that way.